# VBA for combining new columns into a table involving extra work on displaying all possible combinations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, for example:

| Country | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| A | Male |
| B | Female |

Then I have 3 hobbies: sleep, run and play.
Then I have 2 teams: red and blue.

What I want to achieve in vba is to duplicate the table and add hobby and team column after it until all combinations are listed out. In other words, this is a listing combination question, but we need to treat a table as a whole to be a dimension in the combination:

| Country | Gender | Hobby | Team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Male | Sleep | Red |
| B | Female | Sleep | Red |
| A | Male | Sleep | Blue |
| B | Female | Sleep | Blue |
| A | Male | Run | Red |
| B | Female | Run | Red |
| A | Male | Run | Blue |
| B | Female | Run | Blue |
| A | Male | Play | Red |
| B | Female | Play | Red |
| A | Male | Play | Blue |
| B | Female | Play | Blue |

I was thinking first we can list out all combinations of hobby and team. Hobby has 3 values, team has 2.

Then I am thinking we can loop through the each of row within "Country Gender" table and adding the 6 possible combinations of "hobby and team" to it.

But I guess I am just technically not good enough to write this.

thx

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table21"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Country", type text}, {"Gender", type text}}),

//Add columns with a list of Hobbys and Teams
    #"Add Hobby" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Hobby", 
        each {"Sleep","Run","Play"}),
        
    #"Add Team" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Hobby", "Team", 
        each {"Red","Blue"}),

//Expand the lists to new rows
    #"Expanded Hobby" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Team", "Hobby"),
    #"Expanded Team" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Hobby", "Team"),

//Sort to get to your posted order (or omit this step if you want
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Team",{
        {"Hobby", Order.Descending}, 
        {"Team", Order.Descending}, 
        {"Gender", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: i will take a look at this. never used it before. Will follow up if I have further questions. Thanks